# Subclass constructor returns a superclass object

Tags: python, django

I am specializing `django.contrib.gis.geos.Point` just to better create and handle points with *explicity* latitude and longitude.

My current code:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class LLPoint(Point):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lat = kwargs.get('latitude')
        lng = kwargs.get('longitude')

        if lat and lng:
            super(LLPoint, self).__init__(lng, lat)
        elif lat or lng:
            raise TypeError(u'You must both declare latitude and longitude, '
                'not just one of them.')
        else:
            super(LLPoint, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        c = self.coordinates()
        return u'LLPoint Lat: %.5f Lng: %.5f' % (c['latitude'], c['longitude']) 

    def coordinates(self):
        return {
            'latitude': self.coords[1], 
            'longitude': self.coords[0]
        }
```

The problem is:

```
>>> LLPoint(latitude=10.0, longitude=20.0)
<Point object at 0xdeadbeef>
```

Why it is returning a `Point` object? This way I can't use anything that I declared in the subclass. If I try to reproduce the problem with stub classes, it works. This is probably very stupid, but I can't see.

Comment: Looks like this is caused by line 105 in the `_post_init` method called in `__init__` in the `GEOSGeometry` class in `geometry.py`. Not sure of a fix yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Point.__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/gis/geos) calls

```
    super(Point, self).__init__(point, srid=srid)
```

which calls [`GEOSGeometry.__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py#L47), which calls

```
    self._post_init(srid)
```

which executes

```
    self.__class__ = GEOS_CLASSES[self.geom_typeid]
```

which changes the class of `self` to `Point`. Evil.

---

You could try:

```
class LLPoint(Point):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(LLPoint, self).__init__(lng, lat)   # this changes self.__class__ to Point
        ...
        self.__class__ = LLPoint
```